# how to set domain in setcookies()

Tags: php, http, setcookie

I have tried setting cookies but the problem is in setting domain. When i tried to set domain in `setcookies()` it doesn't set any value. Without domain setting it will automatically set my domain (for ex. localhost).

If I am using any `.com` it will set it by default but I cannot set domain in cookies.

Can any one please help me setting domain in php.

```
  setcookie('session_id',$sessionID[1],strtotime($expireTime[1]),'/',$domain);
```

When I set it without domain it sets the cookies to my localhost or on which domain I am.

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not set a cookie attributed to a domain other than that you are using.  this is generally considered a good thing.

Comment: what if i have to set cookie in my header with a domain?which is not actually my domain??

Comment: You simply cant change cookies of someother's domain from your domain. You should consider finding another solution for your work.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a domain to `setcookie`, you'll see in your header that PHP has set your cookie with the right domain name. But, your browser will just ignore it for safety reasons.

If you need to set a cookie for an auto-login or such, you need to play with your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) to make your browser believe that you're on the same domain than the domain where you want to set a cookie.

Example :

If you add :

```
127.0.0.1   autologin.amazon.co.uk
```

in your hosts file, and go to `http://autologin.amazon.co.uk` instead of `http://localhost`, your remote script will be allowed to set any `.amazon.co.uk` cookie.

Comment: but what if i am not on localhost?i might be using any another domain then?thx for your answer btw :)

Comment: @user1487459 why do you want to set a cookie for a different domain? You cannot do that, because of security reasons. If you need such a thing, explain why, and perhaps people can help come up with a working solution.

Comment: I guess he wants to change cookies of domain he doesnt own from his domain. If he would like to change domain in his browser for personal purpose I would suggest javascript consoles. Or edit the cookies in browser as many browsers has this option.

Comment: i am logging in another domain which returns me some cookies i want to set that cookie again and do some task further with http post.

Comment: And I agree with everybody here, fortunately, this is not possible and will never be.

Comment: @user1487459 if you want to auto-login a remote website, you can still play with your hosts file, but instead of 127.0.0.1, you need to put IP of your remote server. Of course, each of your users will need to do that.

Comment: If you want to be able to modify your cookies and http posts, you dont need to do it by PHP. Try to look up an extension that can do it for you for your browser.
e.g https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/